# Cometd в Angular6

Tags: angular

Всем привет!
Подскажите, есть ли возможность использовать Cometd в Angualar? Конкретно в 6 версии. Не могу найти ни одного примера. Или в Angualar единственный вариант - это WebSocket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Конкретно в 6 версии

Вам не нужно привязываться к Angular, `cometd` это обычный пакет.

> Не могу найти ни одного примера

Интернет сам по себе не кипит примерами по CometD, не то, что с Angular. Работал с `cometd` очень-очень давно, но сейчас сообщество добавило определение типов - `@types/cometd`, все что вам нужно это установить соответствующие пакеты:

```
yarn add cometd
yarn add -D @types/cometd
```

В Angular вся бизнес логика изолируется в сервисы, так и у вас должен быть отдельный сервис:

```
import { Observable, Subject, of } from 'rxjs';
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { CometD, Message } from 'cometd';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class CometDService {
  private cometd = new CometD({
    url: '...',
    logLevel: 'info'
  });

  public disconnect(): Observable<Message> {
    return new Observable((observer) => {
      this.cometd.disconnect((message) => {
        observer.next(message);
        observer.complete();
      });
    });
  }

  public get connected(): boolean {
    return !this.disconnected;
  }

  public get disconnected(): boolean {
    return this.cometd.isDisconnected();
  }

  public channel<T = any>(channel: string): Observable<T> {
    const channel$ = new Observable<T>((observer) => {
      const subscription = this.cometd.subscribe(channel, (message: Message) => {
        observer.next(message.data);
      });

      return () => {
        this.cometd.unsubscribe(subscription);
        observer.complete();
      };
    });

    return this.handshake().pipe(
      mergeMap(() => channel$)
    );
  }

  private handshake(): Observable<Message> {
    if (this.connected) {
      return of(null);
    }

    return new Observable((observer) => {
      this.cometd.handshake((message) => {
        observer.next(message);
        observer.complete();
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Объяснения:

- `new CometD` - думаю здесь все понятно :)
- `disconnect` - `cometd` использует колбеки, для удобства оборачиваем в поток
- `get connected || get disconnected` - геттеры для удобства
- `private handshake` - соединяется с сервером через Bayeux протокол один раз в случае если еще не соединен
- `public channel` - подписывается на нужный канал и генерирует события, колбек внутри `Observable` возвращает фабрику, при отписке поток закроется вместе с каналом, так мы освобождаем ресурсы, чтобы не было утечек памяти.

Как использовать?

```
@Component({ ... })
export class SomeComponent implements OnDestroy {
  private readonly destroy$ = new Subject<void>();

  constructor(private cometd: CometDService) {
    this.cometd.channel('/some-channel').pipe(
      takeUntil(this.destroy$)
    ).subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }

  public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.destroy$.next();
    this.destroy$.complete();
  }
}
```

Так как вы работаете с CometD - я думаю вам не составит труда разобраться дальше как управлять каналами и расширять сервис согласно вашим требованиям.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Comment: В вашем примере: вызываю метод channel с параметром ('myChannel'), но cometd ломится на сервер по запросу myUrl/cometd/handshake и возвращает 404. Продублировал проблему в https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55721969/java-ee-cometd-angular

Comment: @Gwynbleidd, хмм, довольно странно, но в том вопросе вам уже ответил сам лид cometd, я думаю от него будет гораздо больше пользы

Comment: проблема скорее всего на сервере. Я до конца не понимаю как правильно его сконфигурировать. Тимлид ответил мне до того как я опубликовал свой код. Надеюсь увидит изменения